# Preparing a SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I apologize if this is not the right place for this.

I have a 250 GB SSD that has two paritions on it, one linux and one win10. I want to make it one single partition, erase everything there, and than install just win10 on it.

What is the recommended way to do this? I've used GParted in the past to create the two paritions that are on it now. Should I boot from a USB with linux on it, select GParted, and reform the 2 partitions into one single empty partition? And then install windows 10 on that (also from a USB).

Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to handle it would be when you install Windows 10 you can delete the existing partitions and let windows repartition the drive to use all of the space.

Comment: Does it matter that the linux partition is a different file system/type (ext4)?

Comment: Nope, it will just be listed as "unknown type" but you can still delete it, you just can't choose it as the target partition to install windows on.

Comment: Okay great, and I will be able to delete it, re-combine it with the current windows partition, and then do a fresh install on top of it?

Comment: Personally I would recommend deleting both and starting fresh, but yes you can install over it. Once you are booted in windows I know you can resize the partition. I don't know if you can resize it during the install though, you may have to wait till you are fully installed to resize.

Comment: I agree. Don't try to combine or resize the existing partitions; just delete what's there and create new ones during installation. Since you're planning to wipe everything out anyhow, there's no point in spending the time waiting for the partition to resize or handle existing files. At best, it'll be wasted time. At worst, there may be conflicts or existing filesystem damage that will cause problems.

Comment: Okay so I am a bit unclear. Just use the windows installer to install over both partitions? Will it just lump them back together in one big partition thru the install process? Remember, one is linux and one is windows 10. Or do you mean delete both in a separate operation (using Gparted or something like it?) and then install on top of the two empty/cleaned partitions?

Comment: Start the windows 10 installer, go to "Advanced" mode, delete ALL partitions on the drive so you end up with a drive with 0 partitions, choose the unpartitioned drive in the installer as the target and windows will create the partitions it needs on the unpartitioned drive.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. Thank you both for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) (or HBCD as it's known), and install that onto a USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make it bootable. From there, you can boot into Mini Windows XP and use the some of the [included tools](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P14/Disk%20Wipe) to reimage and repatition your SSD. After that, you can just install Win10 again.

OR, alternatively, you can just wipe the SSD through the Win10 installer USB. It provides a simple paritioning system when installing Win10.